# Installation of the Gen 6 X1C fingerprint reader on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

How I can install Lenovo X1 carbon fingerprint reader on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Also not supported.

Comment: Somebody working on this at the moment:
(https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90)
Hopefully, Lenovo releases a driver for this too.